# Superimposed (put curves on top of each other) in one region

Tags: plotting

If I have the following data:

https://pastebin.com/AVFwHkC8

or

https://pastebin.com/6kSJBLkR  (this is the same data with two extra sets)

Which plotted like this: `ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]` gives:

[image]

**Question:**

1)How can I make each curve to superimposed (lie on top of each other) in the region between 40 and 65 (x-axis)?
2) How can I give a different color to each curves when plotting the data?
**UPDATED:**
3) How can I put a legend inside the plot with labelling each curve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How to give a different color?

The raw data is a list of 1400 coordinate points.  The data can be reshaped as 5 individual lists of 280 coordinate pairs.

```
Clear[data]
Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/AVFwHkC8", "Data"];
newshape = ArrayReshape[data, {5, 280, 2}];
```

Now `ListPlot[newshape]` will give a different color to each curve.

#### How to superpose the curves *without distortion*?

An approximate way is to shift each curve up or down so its 50th data point, say, lies on the x-axis.  Plots at different scales show the 5 shifted curves happen to cross one another at points near x=49.54.

```
shifted = # /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y - #[[50, 2]]} &  /@ newshape;
ListPlot[shifted, PlotRange -> All]
ListPlot[shifted, PlotRange -> {{20, 85}, {-1, 1}}]
ListLinePlot[shifted, PlotRange -> {{40, 65}, {-0.025, 0.025}}]
```

[image]

The last plot hints at the amount of distortion that would be required to really superimpose the curves throughout the region.

#### Sensitivity

As it turns out, choosing the 50th data point of each curve worked fairly well.  But what if another index had been used?  We can use `Manipulate` to test other values of the index like this:

```
Manipulate[
 shifted = # /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y - #[[ndx, 2]]} &  /@ newshape;
 GraphicsColumn[{
   ListPlot[shifted, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Small],
   ListLinePlot[shifted,
    PlotRange -> {{40, 65}, {-0.025, 0.025}}, 
    ImageSize -> Small]
   }],
 {{ndx, Length[shifted[[1]]]/5, ndx}, 1, Length[shifted[[1]]], 1}]
```

[image]

We can change the value of the index to see how that affects the overlay of the curves.

#### Toward an automated method

It may be possible to use the manipulator on several different datasets to develop a method of choosing the index that determines the amount of the shift.  For instance, it may be found that 20th data point is a good choice if the curves are to overlay between x=20 and x=40.

Another strategy may be to shift the curve so that some data point near the middle of the valley between the first two peaks lies on the x-axis.

Combine `PeakDetect` and `Position` commands to find the indices for the peaks and take it from there.

#### PlotLegends

The questions on this site contain many good examples of using `PlotLegends`.  If you have a some specific case that is not working for you, please post the troublesome code in a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much Louis! Is there any way to do it automatically? For example by selecting the range of all data were I want to superimposed (e.g 40 to 65 of the x axis in this case). In other case, It can be from 20 to 40 or something like that, so I was wondering if there is a way to make it automatic?

Comment: Thanks LouisB! Can you look at the data that has two data sets? That one doesn't seem to work with the code and I am not sure how to fix it